Spark Job Fails with "Remote RPC client disassociated" Error but Doesn't Return Exit Code
I'm facing an issue with a Spark job that runs daily. The job is submitted via a shell script, which waits for the job's completion and checks its return code. Based on this return code, the shell wrapper sends success or failure emails.
Here’s a simplified version of the Spark code:
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

CURRENT_DATE = sys.argv[1]

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Job") \
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 2000) \
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", 2000) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("set spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true")

df = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.DATE = '{CURRENT_DATE}'")

df.write.partitionBy("CURRENT_DATE").mode("append").parquet("bucket_path")

query = f"ALTER TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (DATE='{CURRENT_DATE}');"
spark.sql(query)

Problem:
The Spark job selects data from external tables and writes it to a private cloud storage (MinIO). Recently, I’ve been encountering this error intermittently:
ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 70 on XX.XX.XXX.XX: Remote RPC client disassociated.  Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
The issue occurs randomly: sometimes once a month, other times multiple times in a week. When it happens:

The Spark UI shows the job as finished, but no return code is sent to the shell wrapper, leaving the process in a "ghost" state.
No success or failure email is sent, as the shell script relies on the return code.
In some cases, Spark automatically retries and it completes successfully.

Question:
I need help in handling this scenario. Ideally, I want one of the following solutions:

The job should fail clearly with a proper return code if this error occurs.
If possible, Spark should automatically resubmit the job.
At the very least, I want the shell wrapper to detect the failure and send an alert email.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Any suggestions on how to handle the failure or make sure the shell script receives a return code?
Note: I've modified the code for confidentiality purposes.
